# Elasticsearch find the value of a dynamic key inside an object

Tags: elasticsearch, groovy, elasticsearch-2.0, elasticsearch-query

My partial mapping is as follows (I am still using ES2.4):

```
"name": {
  "type": "string"
},
"misc": {
  "type": "object",
  "dynamic": "true",
  "properties": {}
}
```

Lets assume there is only one document in my storage, as follows

```
{
  "name": "foobar",
  "misc": {
    "201804": 1,
    "201805": 10,
    "201806": 2,
    "201807": 1,
    "201808": 9,
    "201809": 1,
    "201810": 8,
    "201811": 1,
    "201812": 11
  }
}
```

In my search query, I have groovy script, where I am trying to find the value of the key inside `misc` object

```
dynamic_key = ....my logical calculation to find key....
//assume the calculated value of dynamic_key is "201808"
kvalue = doc['misc'][dynamic_key].value //value of kvalue should be 9 as dynamic_key="201808"
```

I get this error `type: "no_class_def_found_error",
reason: "java/lang/Throwable"` , so the dynamic key value selection fails. If I change this line `kvalue = doc['misc'][dynamic_key].value` to `kvalue = doc['misc.201805].value` then it finds the value correctly.

Any idea how to achieve what I am looking for?

Comment: Has the mapping not changed after indexing the given doc?

Comment: It's new index with this mapping always

Comment: You can remove the mapping for `misc` because while inserting the doc, ES tries to create one for you

Comment: Thank you Chandra. I did it and now the previous error is gone and I get this error now `type: "no_class_def_found_error",
reason: "java/lang/Throwable"` , so the dynamic key value selection fails. If I change this line `kvalue = doc['misc'][dynamic_key].value` to `kvalue = doc['misc.201805].value` then it finds the value correctly.

Comment: Even though it's a json object, it is indexed as flat list of key-value pairs. Refer: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/object.html#object

Comment: Ah..I see thanks for educating me :). So now the question boiled down to how to have this dynamic key in my script.

Comment: In groovy, if I can build string `misc.201805` , then I can use it.

Comment: @ChandraPraneethN I quickly tried `kk = 'misc.${dynamic_key}'
lmin = doc[kk].value` and it seems strings are not concating and I get `No field found for [misc.${dynamic_key}] in mapping with types [mydocuments]"`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168139/discussion-between-jvk-and-chandra-praneeth-n).

Comment: Voila, I got it. I had to just change single quote to double `kk = "misc.${dynamic_key}"` . Thanks @ChandraPraneethN

Comment: Glad it worked!